# Auto-fill 2nd text input based on range condition when filling the first input using Nuxt/Vue & Vuetify

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am building a contractor registration form using Nuxt & Vuetify.

I have a form where is the 1st input (ONE), the user needs to key in a contract value (e.g: 50 dollars). On the 2nd input (TWO), it will auto-fill a string value depending on the range of the contract value located. After finish fill the form, user will submit the form.

The pseudocode will be something like this:

```
Let say the user write "13" on the 1st input, 2nd input will auto display "b2".

if ( ONE < 10 ) {
    TWO = "a1" //2nd input will display a1
} else if ( 10 < ONE < 20) {
    TWO = "b2" //2nd input will display b2
} else if ( 20 < ONE < 30) {
    TWO = "c3" //2nd input will display c3
}
```

This is what I've done so far:

nuxt/vue template

```html
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
    <label style="font-size: 1.5rem;">Estimated Contract Value (RM)</label>
    <v-text-field
         v-model="editedItem.EstimatedContractValue"
         outlined
    ></v-text-field>
</v-col>
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
     <label style="font-size: 1.5rem;">Works Grade</label>
     <v-text-field
         v-model="editedItem.WorksGrade"
         outlined
         :items="worksgrade"
      ></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

script

```
watch: {
    "editedItem.EstimatedContractValue"(newVal) {
            this.worksgrade = [];
            if (this.EstimatedContractValue < 200000) {
                // this.editedItem.WorksGrade = "G1";
                this.editedItem.worksgrade.push("G1");
            } else if (200000 < this.EstimatedContractValue < 500000) {
                // this.editedItem.WorksGrade = "G2";
                this.editedItem.worksgrade.push("G2");
            } else if (500000 < this.EstimatedContractValue < 1000000) {
                // this.editedItem.WorksGrade = "G3";
                this.editedItem.worksgrade.push("G3");
            } else if (1000000 < this.EstimatedContractValue < 3000000) {
                // this.editedItem.WorksGrade = "G4";
                this.editedItem.worksgrade.push("G4");
            } else {
                alert("oi lebih dah ni!")
            }
        }
}
```

Currently 2nd input doesn't display anything after I filled the 1st input. I'm using watchers but not sure if that's the right way. How can I do this with Nuxt & Vuetify?
[image: Form inputs]

Answer (score 1):

**If/Else condition:**

This is not valid way to evaluate less than/greater than in the same condition:

```
200000 < this.EstimatedContractValue < 500000
```

It should be separated by `&&` and the variable name should be `newVal` because that's how you defined the value in the watcher parameter:

```
200000 < newVal && newVal < 500000
```

[image]

**Reactivity of editedItem object**

Is `editedItem` a computed object as in the below example? If it is, then `this.WorksGrade = "G1"` will work as you want. If it's in data and not computed, then you need to set the value with `this.$set(this.editedItem, 'WorksGrade', 'G1')`. [Documentation on Vue reactivity for objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

```js
data: () => ({
  EstimatedContractValue: null,
  WorksGrade: null,
}),
computed: {
  editedItem() {
    return {
      EstimatedContractValue: this.EstimatedContractValue,
      WorksGrade: this.WorksGrade,
    }
  },
},
watch: {
  EstimatedContractValue(value) {
    /* your code setting works grade */
  }
},
```

In your case I don't recommend setting the second value in the watcher because as the user is typing the first value, the watcher will run each character. Instead add `@blur="updateWorksGrade` to the first field so the second value is updated when the first field loses focus.

```
updateWorksGrade(event) {
  const contractValue = event.target.value;
  /* your code setting works grade */
}
```

Comment: Hi @Muge, Apologise for not even replying to your answer. It's just that I do not that quite understand how to really solve it and I don't even know how to ask a follow-up question to this haha. But thanks for your help in correcting me on writing proper if/else range statements and your suggestion on using blur instead of watchers.

Comment: I have created a follow-up question on S/O where my second input keeps showing the same value even though my first input is changing every time. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469063/second-input-keep-showing-the-same-input-value-eventhough-the-value-in-the-first